# How to split string variables into two array object variables using powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I need to split ips and hostnames from the below the input and convert into array object using powershell
I have a input like below

```
$docu_results = 'existing IPs: "192.168.1.12","","192.168.1.15","192.168.1.16"
existing hostname: "node.example.com","node1.example.com","node2.example.com",""'
```

my expected output would be like below

```
$existing_ips = "192.168.1.12","","192.168.1.15","192.168.1.16"
$existing_hosts = "node.example.com","node1.example.com","node2.example.com",""
```

The above variables existing_ips an d existing_hosts might have empty or null value and its equivalent values in between these variables and i need to save that in a separate variables

Final output would be like below

```
192.168.1..12 :: node.example.com

192.168.1..15
192.168.1..15 :: node2.example.com
192.168.1..16
missing data: 
 value is missing for '' -> 'node1.example.com' 
 value is missing for '192.168.1.16' -> ''
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there may be more concise solutions, for conceptual clarity I'd use a multi-step approach based on [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) and [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator):

```
$docu_results = 'existing IPs: "192.168.1.12","","192.168.1.15","192.168.1.16"
existing hostname: "node.example.com","node1.example.com","node2.example.com",""'

# Extract the two sub-lists from the input string.
$ipList, $hostList = 
  $docu_results -split 'existing IPs:|existing hostname:' -ne ''

# Split each list into an array of its elements.
$existing_ips = $iplist.Trim() -split ',' -replace '"'
$existing_hosts = $hostList.Trim() -split ',' -replace '"'
```

Note:

- With an *array* as the LHS, PowerShell comparison operators act as *filters* (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66608759/45375)), which means that `-ne ''` above filters out any empty tokens from the array that the `-split` operation outputs; an empty(-string) token results from the fact that one of the separators is at the very start of the input string.

Comment: thank you so much @mklement0.. You saved my time 

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @SuganthanRaj; my pleasure.